# No me muestra la información de mis relaciones - Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando extraer la información de cada usuario que comento en una venta.

Tengo 3 modelos:

- Venta
- User
- Comentario

La manera en que tengo relacionado es así.

Modelo `Venta.php`:

```
public function Comentario()
{   
 return $this->HasMany(Comentario::class);
}

public function User()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Modelo `Comentario.php`:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::Class);
}
public function Venta()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Venta::class);
}
```

Por último Modelo `User.php`:

```
 public function Comentario(){
    return $this->HasMany(Comentario::class);
 }

public function Venta(){
   return $this->HasMany(Venta::class);
 }
```

De esta forma estoy haciendo la consulta:

```
$comentarios = Comentario::with(['venta','user'])
                        ->where('venta_id',1)
                        ->first();
//  Puse  (el 1) fijo  ya que ahorita por andar probando
```

hice un  `dd()`:

> ```
> Comentario {#631 ▼
>   #connection: "mysql"
>   #table: null
>   #primaryKey: "id"
>   #keyType: "int"
>   +incrementing: true
>   #with: []
>   #withCount: []
>   #perPage: 15
>   +exists: true
>   +wasRecentlyCreated: false
>   #attributes: array:6 [▶]
>   #original: array:6 [▶]
>   #changes: []
>   #casts: []
>   #dates: []
>   #dateFormat: null
>   #appends: []
>   #dispatchesEvents: []
>   #observables: []
>   #relations: array:2 [▼
>     "venta" => Venta {#666 ▶}
>     "user" => null
>   ]
>   #touches: []
>   +timestamps: true
>   #hidden: []
>   #visible: []
>   #fillable: []
>   #guarded: array:1 [▶]
> }
> ```

Si se nota en las relaciones, tengo la información de la venta. pero no obtengo la información del usuario que hizo un comentario.

¿qué estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: El usuario de venta no tiene por qué ser el mismo que el del comentario, ¿no? ¿Te obtiene la información del usuario de venta?

Comment: ¿Tu llave foránea que conecta al modelo usuario con comentario está bien?, ¿cómo se llama?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulta que está es mi tabla de migración

Exactamente en donde dice **usuario_id** tenía que ponerlo en mi modelo.
comentario.

```html
Schema::create('comentarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('descripcion',240);


            $table->integer('venta_id')
            ->unsigned();

            $table->integer('usuario_id')
            ->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('venta_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('ventas')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('usuario_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

así es como debería de estar mi modelo comentario. pasarle el parametro, O en este caso cambiarle el nombre. que se llama usuario_id

```html
   public function User()
    {

     return $this->belongsTo(User::Class,'usuario_id');
    }
```

Y entonces funciono!

Comment: Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada si resolvió tu problema